# Sentence meaning: "be appropriately placed in the context of prior and existing research"

Tags: sentence-meaning

[Here](https://ees.elsevier.com/journal/ELS_Plagiarism.html), it states that "... that the paper should: ... be appropriately placed in the context of prior and existing research. "

What does "be appropriately placed in the context of prior and existing research" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

It means that a paper should acknowledge the influence and contributions of relevant prior and existing research. For example, if you are writing a paper about black holes, it would be unethical to ignore the contributions of Stephen Hawking.

Science is a collaborative process, and most scientific discoveries are incremental expansions of knowledge that build on centuries of work by other researchers that came before. Any paper that does not give credit to the preceding literature in the same field is displaying a lack of academic honesty.